# How to read xml file and plot it to WebMatrix (C#) page

Tags: c#, xml, razor, webmatrix

I have never so much as successfully loaded an xml document in WebMatrix (or JavaScript for that matter), despite how many times I have tried.

No online example is complete or accurate.

if I had an xml file that contained this (and only this):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<someNode>
    <someValue>HEY THERE! I'M XML!</someValue>
    <someValueTwo>Another Value</someValueTwo>
</someNode>
```

How could I (start from loading the xml document etc.) plot the values of the two elements on one of my WebMatrix pages (please include where the code you are providing goes, as I have no clue).

Please include all the places I would need the code not just loading or writing to page.

************UPDATE:*********

Oh, well, nvm, xml is useless anyway, I'll just use another database or render the contents of another external cshtml page or something.

I have looked at XPath before and such, but I am not really worried about selecting them by tagname, id, attribute, etc because researching that would have been easy.

Sometimes I wonder why XML is still around...(Yes, I know it (is supposed to) help communicate data across very different languages and platforms) but the truth is, even with online tutorials and walkthroughs, it doesn't work, and it doesn't seem like there's anyone left who does know how to do this really.  Why is it still around? Isn't it time that WebMatrix got rid of the xml based methods, since they don't work, and since there isn't anyone left who knows how to so much as try to load an xml file without getting errors?

Just curious if xml will be faded out in future updates.

************UPDATE:*********

Okay, I'm told that xml is supposed to still be useful. Do you just have to not be me to get it to work, lol?

Answer (score 1):

I've never done anything with WebMatrix so I'm not gonna have much to say on that front. I am however confused by your attitude toward XML. If you mean only that XML is not useable in the WebMatrix context I can neither confirm nor deny that; however XML is dead useful in a plethora of other scenarios, and it is unclear from your question if you know that or not. Sorry I can't help on your question, just clarifying that XML is a very powerful tool as far as data file formats are concerned.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of got the impression that it was supposed to be (or was at one point in time), but cars are supposed to be very useful for transportation, but if it's broke... I have also tried to use xml with JavaScript, but it is just as broken there. I assumed for a long time that I just wasn't doing it right, but I have seen and tried over 50 different examples/tutorials across various languages and tried each probably 10 different ways, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Why can't it be as easy as jQuery? (use css element selector, which everyone knows and is super easy, then get value of html, assign to a variable, then use at leisure).  But XPath seems designed to be as backwards as possible... Anyway, XPath isn't even the point, I could get that if I needed to, but simply loading the xml document then plotting a value on the page is (in my experience) just not possible, no matter how many ways you try it. Then when you ask a community for help it gets so quiet you could hear a pen drop, so I assumed that it was a deprecated language or something.

Comment: Anyway, like you said, it's not an answer, but I'm voting your post up because at least you are providing useful information. Thnx for that. If you can use it in JavaScript, you should perhaps share that...

Comment: I've honestly only extensively used xml in a c# context. Within .net there is a XmlDocument object which makes xml creation and reading streamlined and incredibly simple. I may be able to play around with trying to get something in javascript working, however I don't have a web programming environment set up yet (As I haven't done much JS in a while I'll be useless w/o some kind of syntax highlighting), so it may not be for a while, and then only when I'm not at work o.O